# Windows 8 Hyper-V fails to boot Windows XP ISO

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, iso-image, hyper-v, boot

So I recently installed Windows 8 Professional on my computer and today I enabled Hyper-V with the intention of creating a Windows XP virtual machine.

I created the virtual machine with standard settings but I selected "Image file (.iso)" at the "Install operating system from a boot CD/DVD-ROM" screen.
I pointed to my Windows XP ISO image and completed the wizard.

After that I connected to the newly created virtual machine and started it but instead of a Windows XP installation setup it showed this message: "Boot failure. Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device".

I tried other variations of settings. Tried mounting the image in Windows 8 and capturing it in the virtual machine but it still didn't work.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it a proper bootable XP Pro ISO, preferably x86 version with SP3?

Comment: I downloaded it from MSDN so I suppose it's a good image. It is x86 with SP3, yes.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new VM without that option and *later* loading the ISO to see if it boots and starts Setup?

Comment: Yes, tried that too.

Comment: Hi, I solved this one. Apparently there was something wrong with the Windows XP ISO image. I don't know what that was because it booted just fine on the physical pc.

Anyway, I downloaded another image from MSDN and that one worked just fine with Hyper-V.

Thank you for the help @Karan!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you downloaded the actual operating system image from MSDN (**Windows XP Professional with Service Pack 3**), not just the service pack (**Windows XP Service Pack 3 - CD**).

Seems like when you search MSDN for Windows XP .iso, this service pack download pops up first in the list of results.